How to reinstall GRUB on a different device/partition?
I have a laptop that comes with Windows pre-installed. Recently I bought an extra 1TB external SSD and installed both Fedora (first) and Kali Linux (after) on it.
With Fedora, only when I connect the external SSD to my laptop is there an option to choose to boot into Fedora on the boot device menu. When the external SSD is unplugged, there is only "Windows Boot Manager" option that presents.
I expected it would be the same after I installed Kali Linux alongside Fedora but it was not. Despite the external SSD being disconnected from my laptop, there is still an option for Kali on the boot device menu. My guess is that may be one small component of Kali Linux was installed on the same disk with Windows and the rest was installed on the external SSD (as it appears in the pictures below).
When I plug in the external SSD.


When I unplug the external SSD.
My question is: is there any way that I can make it behave like Fedora, meaning that it only shows an option for Kali Linux when I connect the external SSD to my laptop, and when I do not, there will be no other options than "Windows Boot Manager"?
I'm sorry if the question in the title is not the right question to ask. I honestly do not know what to search either. I'm new to computer and Linux, and I really appreciate all the answers.
Edit: Here are some more information:
fdisk -l of the internal disk:

fdisk -l of the external SSD:

lsblk -o +PARTUUID returns:

efibootmgr -v returns:


What partitions does the external disk have? Some OS installers have been written to always create a new EFI System Partition on the same disk; other installers always try to re-use an existing one.

If you update grub in Fedora, does it add Kali to boot menu? Only one boot loader is default. Also external drives boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi using drive name or label which UEFI finds, just like every installer flash drive. But that is only one file & will boot last install unless updated. If Fedora boots Kali like it should you can just remove Kali from the folder in the Windows drive & the Kali UEFI boot entry using that folder.

The fact that the firmware boot menu can display names of operating systems indicates you have an UEFI-capable system, currently booting in UEFI native mode.

My guess is that may be one small component of Kali Linux was installed on the same disk with Windows and the rest was installed on the external SSD (as it appears in the pictures below).

That guess seems correct to me. More specifically, the "one small component" is the GRUB core image in the form of the grubx64.efi file, located presumably in the EFI/kali/ directory of the EFI system partition of the internal disk. When Kali is running, that partition should be mounted at /boot/efi/, and so you'll find all the things Kali added to the internal disk at /boot/efi/EFI/kali/. There should also be a /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/ directory, containing the Windows Boot Manager respectively.

is there any way that I can make it behave like Fedora, meaning that it only shows an option for Kali Linux when I connect the external SSD to my laptop, and when I do not, there will be no other options than "Windows Boot Manager"?

You would have to mount the EFI System Partition (ESP for short) of the external SSD to /boot/efi/ instead of the internal disk's ESP. Since Fedora behaves the way you described, it must already have created a valid ESP on the external SSD.
Then use grub-install to reinstall kali's GRUB to the external SSD; the fact that the new ESP is mounted to /boot/efi/ should be enough to tell grub-install to use it. It should automatically create the /boot/efi/EFI/kali directory and populate it, and create a NVRAM boot variable for it.
After this, you may end up with an extra entry for kali in your firmware boot menu; one that will always be visible, and the other that will be visible only when the external SSD is plugged in. If that happens, you'll need to use the efibootmgr command to delete the older entry. If you are unsure how to use the efibootmgr command, please edit your question to add the output of the commands efibootmgr -v and lsblk -o +PARTUUID.

Note that as it is now, the external SSD will be easily bootable on your system only: other systems won't have the NVRAM boot variables telling the firmware about Kali and Fedora being bootable from a particular ESP uniquely identified by its PARTUUID. If that's fine for you, you won't have to do anything else.
But if you want the external SSD to be bootable on any UEFI-capable x86_64 PC you plug it into, you will have to make a few more changes. First, you will need to select either Fedora or Kali to be the "owner OS" of the removable media/fallback bootloader. This will be the OS whose GRUB will be offered by default when you plug the SSD to a new system and select to boot from it. You can then add the other OS to the menu of that OS's GRUB to make both OSs accessible. But without setting up NVRAM boot variables in advance, the firmware boot selection menu won't be able to show the names of the OSs.
To add the removable media/fallback bootloader, boot into either Fedora or Kali, then run grub-install --removable. It will create a second copy of the bootloader at /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi, creating the directory and adding any necessary other files automatically.
Resetting the BIOS settings to factory defaults, or a UEFI firmware update (sometimes called "BIOS update" for legacy reasons) may or may not clear the UEFI NVRAM boot variables. If the boot variables get cleared, having the removable media/fallback bootloader on the external media helps too. (On the internal SSD, Windows has probably already placed a copy of its bootloader in the equivalent position.)

I've added some extra information that you requested. And here are steps that I should take based on your advice, given that /dev/nvme0n1p1 is ESP on internal disk and /dev/sda2 is ESP on external SSD,  please help me make sure they're correct: 1) umount /boot/efi from /dev/nvme0n1p1. 2) mount /dev/sda2 /boot/efi. 3) Change the UUID of /dev/nvme0n1p1 to that of /dev/sda2 in /etc/fstab for next reboot. 4) sudo grub-install to reinstall GRUB on /dev/sda2 5) Delete the old kali boot option from boot menu and remove it from boot order using efibootmgr -b 4 -B

Looks correct to me. A sudo update-initramfs -u on Kali after all the other steps just to be safe might be a good addition.

Thank you so much for your thoughtful answer! It works perfectly. I don't even have to delete the old Kali entry in the boot menu with efibootmgr. But a last question though, is it safe to manually delete the old EFI/kali/grubx64.efi file in the ESP of the internal drive?

Yes, that can be safely deleted once you've confirmed that the newly installed bootloader works.
